# Enable Wi-Fi using config.txt

Tags: raspbian, wifi

Is there any way I can enable Wi-Fi using `config.txt`? I have seen ways of disabling it but I cannot enable it from SD card.

Answer (score 3):

I've enabled it by putting the new wpa_supplicant.conf file in the boot partition. I have a Linux laptop to do this with, but /boot is a FAT filesystem which can be edited from Window/Mac/Linux.

To enable ssh, just put an empty file called "ssh" in the boot partition.

The next time you boot your Pi, it should copy the wpa_supplicant file over to /etc/wpa_supplicat/wpa_supplicant.conf.

The directions are on [raspberypi.org.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md) (As per @Ingo)

Comment: You could put this link to your answer: [Setting up a Raspberry Pi headless](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md)

Comment: `it should copy` ... it actually copies, then removes the file from `/boot` (for obvious reasons) - might be good to know, because you know someone will get confused

Comment: It fooled me the first time when both files were removed. Then I figured it out and laughed at my own stupidity. Of course it has to remove them.